# What the curvature $2$-form really represents?

Tags: differential-geometry, intuition, curvature, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Let $(E,\pi,B)$ be a principal bundle with structure group $G$. The connection $1$-form can be thought of as a projection on the vertical part. It allows us to characterize the horizontal subspaces as $H_p E = \ker \omega_p$ then.

Apart from that, there's the curvature $2$-form. This object is defined as follows: let $\operatorname{hor}$ mean the projection operator taking a vector field to its horizontal part. Then, if $\eta$ is a $k$-form on $E$ its exterior covariant derivative is the $k+1$ form $D\eta$ defined by

$$D\eta(X_1,\dots,X_{k+1}) = d\eta(\operatorname{hor}X_1,\dots,\operatorname{hor}X_{k+1}).$$

We call the curvature $2$-form then the differential form $\Omega = D\omega$ where $\omega$ is the connection $1$-form.

Although the definition is perfectly clear I can't understand what this object really represents. I mean, when we define curvature for curves on space, the curvature is meant to represent how much the curve deviates from a straight line. On the other hand, when reading books about General Relativity some time ago, I read that the curvature of the Levi-Civita connection is intended to encode the information of the difference between a paralel transported vector around a loop and the starting vector. Those two ideas are more geometric. This curvature $2$-form, on the other hand, I can't understand what it really represents.

So, what the curvature $2$-form really represents? How it relates to those other ideas of curvature? And how this intuition is captured by the rigorous definition?

Comment: $\Omega$ defines a curvature tensor $R$. Take E be the tangent bundle and $\omega$ be the Levi-Civita connection form this is the same curvature tensor of a Riemann manifold.

Comment: Would you say in which book you've read about the geometric interpretation of the Levi-Civita connection? It would be helpful, thank you.

Comment: It is discussed in most GR books. See e.g. Carroll's Spacetime and Geometry and Wald's General Relativity

Answer (score 5):

Remember we are working with principal bundles. Thus, contrary to what other people seem to think, a curvature $2$-form is not the same thing as a Riemann curvature tensor. However, we can get a Riemann curvature tensor from it, in specific cases. We shall discuss that construction momentarily.

Let $P$ be a principal $G$-bundle with projection $\pi:P\to B$. Fixing a connection form $\omega$ on $P$ and a projection $h:TP\to HP$, we define the curvature $2$-form $\Omega$ by $\Omega(X\wedge Y)=\mathrm{d}\omega(hX\wedge hY)$. Expanding this a little further, we get $$\Omega(X\wedge Y)=hX(\omega(hY))-hY(\omega(hX))-\omega([hX,hY])=-\omega([hX,hY]).$$

How might we interpret that? Well, I like to think of it as a measure of **how vertical the bracket of the horizontal projections is**.

Now, if we consider the frame bundle $F_{GL}M$ of a smooth manifold $M$, then we can get a connection on $F_{GL}M$ and pass that information down to $M$. However, in order to do this, we need to talk in terms of specific frames to get specific projections, leading to *la méthode du repère mobile* or, roughly translated, "the method of moving frames." Using this, we can essentially interpret $R$ as the "passed-down version of $\Omega$ on $M$".